# How to stop javascript popup in embedded browser? in windows application?

Tags: watin

Let i show u my problem.

I have one windows application .

In that application we r using watin.

In my application i am using embedded browser.

Using watin we check every mail and check every link.

we used for loop to check all links ,when we embedded browser open link then loop moves and browser open second link. If that first link contains popup/leave page dialog then it popup on browser.

watin can not find that popup then application crashes.

I have tried lot of technique but i fail.

When we try to find that popup we did not get anything.

So ,please give me such a technique so that popup will not come or close that popup using watin.

How to identify that popup.When this popup comes we unable to do anything.

Please give me any technique so that popup can be completely solved.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://julianjelfs.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/watin-javascript-alert-dialog-handler/) post. Of course the built-in could do just the same:

```
WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.AlertDialogHandler adh = new
      WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.AlertDialogHandler();
ie.AddDialogHandler(adh);
```